# Combining multiple string replace into one statement?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is what I'm doing now:

```
text = text.replace(/{{contact first}}/gi, contact.first)
    .replace(/{{contact last}}/gi, contact.last)
    .replace(/{{contact name}}/gi, contact.first + ' ' + contact.last);
```

Is there a way of doing:

```
text = text.replace([
    /{{contact first}}/gi,
    /{{contact last}}/gi,
    /{{contact name}}/gi
], [
    contact.first,
    contact.last,
    contact.first + ' ' + contact.last
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var contact={first:'John',last:'Doe'}

var text='{{contact first}} blah blah {{contact last}} blah blah blah {{contact name}} blahblah';

text= text.replace(/{{contact (first|last|name)}}/gi, function(a, b){   
    return contact[b]|| contact.first+' '+contact.last;
});

text;

/*  returned value: (String)
John blah blah Doe blah blah blah John Doe blahblah
*/
```

Comment: Nice I dropped this right in and it shortened my code quite a bit. `Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.1): Executed 41 of 41 SUCCESS (0.575 secs / 0.021 secs)`

Answer (score 3):

That is not supported in Javascript but you can probably use `String#replace` like this:

```
text = text.replace(/{{contact (first|last|name)}}/gi, function($0, $1) {
    if ($1 == "last") 
       return contact.last;
    else
       return contact.first;
});
```